# Is the argument included in the page list?

Tags: r, list, compare

I want to define the operator `%in%`, whose operation is to return `TRUE` if the argument on the `left` is in the list on the right and `FALSE` otherwise. The task should be implemented without using a loop.

```
### Creating a simple list

ell <- list( 2, c( 2, 5), list( c( 2, 8)), "xyz")

### Testing of selected elements
2 %in% ell
5 %in% ell
list( c( 2, 8)) %in% ell
list( list( 2, 8)) %in% ell
"xyz" %in% ell

[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: So you want to override the built-in `%in%` operator? That might break things in other functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Like MrFlick said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293656/is-the-argument-included-in-the-page-list#comment95408193_54293656), do not override built-in operators, it will definitely break something.
Try this one and see if it does what you want. I have named the new operator `%IN%`, since R is case sensitive.

```
`%IN%` <- function(x, y){
  x %in% unlist(y, recursive = FALSE)
}

2 %IN% ell
#[1] TRUE
5 %IN% ell
#[1] TRUE
list( c( 2, 8)) %IN% ell
#[1] TRUE
list( list( 2, 8)) %IN% ell
#[1] FALSE
"xyz" %IN% ell
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help